# Odoo How to remove Create button in a model without effect to One2many?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-view

I have created two models named Enrollment and Student. In Student Model there is an one2many field called enrollment_ids.

I just want to create Enrollment through that one2many field.

I can remove create button from kanban & form views. But If I remove Create button from tree view I cannot either add enrollment from that one2many field...

How should I complete my Requirement....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have to separate tree view for Enrollment, one for Enrollment's main view the other inside student view :

```
<field name="enrollment_ids" editable="bottom">
    <tree string="This Enrollment tree view inside student">
            <field name="state"/>
            <field name="name"/>      
    </tree>   
    <form string="This Enrollment form view inside student" >
            <field name="state"/>
            <field name="name"/>       
    </form>           
</field>
```

If you still not sure how to do it, just show me your student view xml code.

Comment: It's Worked.. Thanks Buddy...!